# Using <hr> tag in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I've list on active admin index page that looks like this:

```
column 'Schools' do |p|
  p.schools.each do |school|
    div do
      school.name
    end
  end
end
```

but the problem is that I want to separate each school_name with hr tag. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't had the chance to try this but reading the arbre gem documentation I found that this code should do the trick:

```
column 'Schools' do |p|
  p.schools.each do |school|
    div do
      school.name
      hr
    end
  end
end
```